# 'Quite a lot' vs 'a lot'

Tags: meaning, vocabulary

Do these two phrases have the same meaning?

> He met a lot of  people in London.
>
> He met quite a lot of people in London.

or

> I swim a lot.
>
> I swim quite a lot.

Do the above sentences in each pair mean the same thing?

Comment: "Quite" is not there for nothing -- it has its uses. Please see also [ell.se] Good Luck.

Answer (score -1):

There is no difference in the meanings of the sentences.
The difference would be if you compare 'a little' and 'quite a little/bit'. The last one means the same as 'a lot'.
According to Oxford Living Dictionary:
quite a lot (or a bit) -
A considerable number or amount of something.

Comment: So you think the addition of the word 'quite' does not change the meaning of the original _at all_, not even in the slightest?